# How do you use nested component in Angular 2 final release

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-components

In previous RC releases , we got directive tag to use nested component. But in final release of angular 2 , they have removed directive tag from component. Now if i want to put one component into the other what should i do???

I have seen some post where you create a module for grouping the component and then import that module to the app module. But is this the right way to do it ??

Please explain with some example

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your idea is correct. Angular groups all functionality into modules. A module defines the components and directives it owns. So within the component template, you can use any other component or directive from the parent module (or from a module that the current module imported) without having to list it.

I suggest you put in the work to go through the docs on [Angular Modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html). They include thorough explanations and examples.

The module is the defining functionality partition. Basically the design choice of Angular is that components, directives, pipes and services in the same modules are considered pieces of the same puzzle. A component isn't meant to be used outside its module. That's why Angular will force you to place the component in a module before you can use it, and why Angular will thrown an error if you try to declare the same component in more than one module.

Comment: but don't you think in that way we will be loosing the component idea of using it independently with any other module. ???

Comment: Suppose i have create one component for showing some profiles on my page which consist of different component. Then to use this component in some other application i need to copy the module also or i need to create a new module to add the functionality.???  Also this will not remain the self explanatory component because my module can have more dependencies.

Comment: @piyushanwekar I've added a paragraph. A component isn't supposed to be used outside of its module. If you anticipate the need to do that, then make it the only component in the module so that you can plug the whole module in any app you wish to use.